# Libstdc++: wrong version after manually installing .deb-package

Tags: debian, ubuntu, software-installation, dpkg

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`. Kernel is `3.13.0.-92-generic`. I have installed latest available updates.

I am trying make Linux version of [Password Safe](https://github.com/pwsafe/pwsafe/releases/tag/0.99BETA) to work on my computer.

I downloaded `.deb` file for Debian and installed it with `dpkg -i passwordsafe-debian-0.99.9.-BETA.amd64.deb`.

Installation succeeds but when I try to run the program I get:

```
pwsafe: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by pwsafe)
pwsafe: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by pwsafe)
```

I also tried installing `deb`-package for Xubuntu. It gave the same errors.
I tried researching this problem but could not find anything usefull about the prolematic programs/libraries.

What should I do to solve these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors mean the version of Password Safe you have (as built for the package you're installing) needs a newer `libstdc++.so` than the one on your system. Upgrading that library beyond what is supported by your current distribution is *not* a good idea.

There are a few other possibilities.

1. If you don't mind installing an older version of Password Safe, the [System Tools & Utilities](https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/ubuntu/system) PPA has a package for your version of Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/system
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install passwordsafe
   ```
2. The Debian Password Safe package should rebuild fine in Ubuntu 14.04, once a couple of fixes have been applied:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install devscripts build-essential debhelper libgtest-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev libxerces-c-dev libxt-dev libxtst-dev libykpers-1-dev libyubikey-dev locales-all pkgconf uuid-dev wx3.0-headers
   dget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/passwordsafe/passwordsafe_0.99+dfsg-1.dsc
   cd passwordsafe-0.99+dfsg
   sed -i /locales-all/d debian/control
   sed -i s/LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8/LC_ALL=C.UTF-8/ debian/rules
   dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
   sudo dpkg -i ../passwordsafe*_0.99+dfsg-1*deb
   ```

Ubuntu 16.06, which is also an LTS release, includes Password Safe. Thus a third option would be to upgrade to that; but in any case, if you install a package using either of the two options above, when you do eventually upgrade to 16.06 the package will be replaced by the "official" Ubuntu package.

Comment: I went with option 2. but run into new prolem: Package `locales-all` has no installation candidates. I ignored that error and installed rest. Then `dpkg-buildpackage` failed with `Unment build dependencies: dephelper (>=9.0.0) locales-all`. Any idea how I could get `locales-all` to my system?

Comment: @MadocComadrin see my update, I added two `sed` lines which fix the build without `locales-all` (for me at least).

Comment: After using the `sed` commands it no longer complains about `locales-all` but it still says this: `Unment build dependencies: dephelper (>=9.0.0)`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that `debhelper` needs to be installed too; `sudo apt-get install debhelper` should fix things for you (I've updated my answer).

Comment: Installing `debhelper` fixed the last error. Password Safe got installed. Thanks.